# Problem in installing ubuntu alongside windows 10 on DELL laptop

Tags: system-installation

Installation does not show *install Ubuntu alongside Windows*.

I have created Unallocated space of 50 GB from disk management in Window for booting Ubuntu.

But at the time of installation it isn't showing that partition.

Comment: did you make a partition or free space? free space is not a partition

Comment: The correct term is : unallocated space of 50 gb

Comment: then it should give an option to install in the unallocated space.

Comment: @ravery , ur right but it is not showing that un allocated space..  askubuntu has not given me privilege right now , otherwise i would have shown you the picture

Comment: Make sure the SATA mode is AHCI, not IDE or RAID, and disable fast startup in Windows.

Comment: @MichaelBay, Sata mode is AHCI and fast startup is disabled in Windows, but still not working

Comment: Post this: `sudo parted -l` from Ubuntu installer in live mode, using terminal.

Comment: @oldfred, didn't work

Comment: If you cannot even run `sudo parted -l` from terminal then you may have a bad ISO or a bad write to flash drive. check ISO - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM How did you create flash drive installer? Also link on how to create a  bootable DVD or USB flash drive, Windows or Ubuntu, Min hardware requirements
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: Can you boot into a live Ubuntu session via the "Try Ubuntu" option from the bootable USB drive and open a terminal there (Ctrl+Alt+T)? If yes, what's the output of `sudo lsblk -f`? If no, what happens when you select that option and what do you see instead?

Comment: thank's everyone for response . Now the unallocated space is showing, problem was my disk was dynamic and i converted it to basic using testdisk.   @Eliah kagan thanks for sharing ,that helped to solve my query

Answer (score 0):

The best approach would be to:
0 - boot into Ubuntu installation media.
1 - manually divide you hard disk making a free space for Ubuntu.
2 - divide this free space into 1GB and the what ever free space still.
3 - create a new partition for that 1GB and define it a SWAP partition.
4 - create and format the last free space as (primary/logical) partition with EXT4 file system.
5 - install Ubuntu.
6 - have fun.